# How to combine CLI arguments as variables within a perl script

Tags: perl, command-line-interface, snmp

I am trying to write a script that basically executes a cli command like:

`snmpget -v 1 -c xxxxxx-Ovq xx.xx.xx.xxx .1.3.6.1.2.1.1.8.0`

where xxxxx is a password and xx.xx.xx.xxx and IP that normally returns:

`49:22:12:15.00`

My script is:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl

#snmpget -v 1 -c xxxxx -Ovq xx.xx.xx.xxx .1.3.6.1.2.1.1.8.0

$SNMP_GET_CMD = "snmpget -v1 -c xxxxx-Ovq";
$SNMP_TARGET = "xx.xx.xx.xxx";

my $sysORLastChange = '${SNMP_GET_CMD} ${SNMP_TARGET} .1.3.6.1.2.1.1.8.0';
chomp($sysORLastChange);
print("${SNMP_TARGET} as an Input Line Reading of ${sysORLastChange}\n");
```

and the output is:

`xx.xx.xx.xxx as an Input Line Reading of ${SNMP_GET_CMD} ${SNMP_TARGET} .1.3.6.1.2.1.1.8.0`

It should return the following:

`xx.xx.xx.xxx as an Input Line Reading of 49:22:12:15.00`

Is there any problem with the syntax i used in the script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Perl, use double-quotes to interpolate another variable into a string. When you define `$sysORLastChange` using other variables within a single-quoted string like this:

```
my $sysORLastChange = '${SNMP_GET_CMD} ${SNMP_TARGET} .1.3.6.1.2.1.1.8.0';
```

...the string is being assigned verbatim (ie. the inner variables aren't being expanded).

To correct this, assign to the variable using double-quotes, which will interpolate the inner variables into their values:

```
my $sysORLastChange = "${SNMP_GET_CMD} ${SNMP_TARGET} .1.3.6.1.2.1.1.8.0";
```

If you want to actually execute the string, you can use the `qx()` operator, aka the "backtick" style quotes:

```
my $sysORLastChange = qx(${SNMP_GET_CMD} ${SNMP_TARGET} .1.3.6.1.2.1.1.8.0);

# or...

my $sysORLastChange = `${SNMP_GET_CMD} ${SNMP_TARGET} .1.3.6.1.2.1.1.8.0`;
```

See [Perl Quote and Quote-like Operators](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-and-Quote-like-Operators) in [perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html).

Comment: I think the OP wants to actually *execute* the `snmpget` command, interpolating the *result* into the variable.

Comment: To execute the interpolated string change the double quotes to `qx(...)`.

Comment: @stevieb Ok I did not notice that the actual mistake was using `'` instead of `\``. Details...